# String partial implementation using a vector

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel

I saw few similar solutions, but they all relied on C-style arrays and str utils, so I thought I would write a higher level C++ only implementation with a vector as an exercise. I have not implemented all the functions yet but wanted to first check if this looks to be on the right path or if there are some major issues.

```
class mystring {
public:
mystring() = default;
explicit mystring(const char* str) {
    if (str != nullptr) {

        data = std::vector<char>(str, str + strlen(str));
    }
}

mystring& operator=(const char* str) {
    data.clear();
    copy(str, str + strlen(str), back_inserter(data));
}

mystring& operator+=(const mystring& other) {
    data.insert(data.end(), other.data.begin(),other.data.end());
    return *this;
}

mystring operator+(const mystring& other) const {
    mystring result(other);
    result += other;
    return result;
}

explicit operator const char* () const {
    return c_str();
}

const char& operator[](size_t idx) const {
    return data[idx];
}

char& operator[](size_t idx) {
    return data[idx];
}

void replace(size_t b, size_t e, const char* str) {
    data.erase(data.begin()+b, data.begin() + e);
    data.insert(data.begin()+b,str,str+strlen(str));
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, const mystring& s);

bool operator==(const mystring& o) const =default;

const char* c_str() const {
    return data.data();
}

private:
std::vector<char> data;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Inconsistent handling of `nullptr`s

Your constructor checks if `str` might be `nullptr`, but your assignment operator does not. Choose whether you want to support `nullptr` arguments, and then handle it consistently.

I would personally choose to not allow `nullptr` arguments, and add `assert(str)` statements to check for that in debug builds. Consider that the C string functions also don't handle `NULL`.

## Missing `NUL`-byte

When you construct a `mystring`, you only copy everything but the terminating `NUL`-byte. However, that means `c_str()` will return a pointer to a non-terminated string. Make sure you always have a terminating `NUL`-byte at the end of `data`.

## Consider not adding any assignment operator

You declared an assignment operator that handles `const char*`s, but the compiler also generated a default assignment operator that takes another `mystring` as the right hand side, as if there was:

```
mystring& operator=(const mystring& other) = default;
```

If you would remove your custom assignment operator, then assignments from `const char*` will still work: since you have a constructor that takes `const char*`, the compiler will see that it can construct a new `mystring` from it first, and then assign it. Since it will also implement the move assignment operator automatically, it's even as efficient, or even more so (as `copy(…, back_inserter(…))` might inefficiently insert one character at a time).

## `replace()` is inefficient

Your `replace()` function will likely move parts of the string twice: once during erasure, and other time during insertion. It is probably more efficient to *overwrite* as much as possible, then just erase or insert the remainder.

## `std::string` doesn't have an `operator const char*()`

There is no conversion operator from `std::string` to `const char*`. It's good that you made yours `explicit`, that avoids a lot of problems. However, it might be better to omit it altogether, to avoid any accidental conversions.

Comment: much appreciated, learned so much from your review

Comment: On the assignment operator does not handle mystring - I thought defaults are removed only if the user provided copy/move operator match the full signatures. If I try to write some assignments or use copy constructor it compiles even if  but if I add some random move assignment operator all the default operators are deleted and it fails to compile, e.g.
mystring& operator=(const mystring&& other) {
        return *this;
    }

So it does not like it is because of some implicit casting going on. I guess I am missing something trivial again here.

Comment: You are right, the default assignment operators are still generated. I've updated the answer. It's still the case that it's probably better to not implement any assignment operators.

Comment: Always follow the **rule 0/3/5**. https://images.app.goo.gl/zYYFXjMBKjs4fupEA https://www.foonathan.net/2019/02/special-member-functions/

Answer (score 1):

If you have unvalidated accesses operators:

```
const char& operator[](size_t idx) const {
    return data[idx];
}

char& operator[](size_t idx) {
    return data[idx];
}
```

Then you better have a way to validate that you are in range. So you really need to provide a `size()` or `length()` method!!!

---

Your `c_str()` is broken:

```
const char* c_str() const {
    return data.data();
}
```

If you are returning a C-String then it needs to be null-terminated. Your data is not null terminated (you don't copy the null from the C-String into your vector).